Status of a manuscript whose required reviews are completed
I have submitted a paper to a good math journal in first week of May 2024. After a month (+ a week at most), the online system shows the status “Required reviews completed”. However, to this day, I haven't received any email from the  journal regarding the review report.
I wonder whether I should send a polite email to inquire about the status of manuscript.
I am aware that getting review reports within three months in the field of mathematics (especially pure math) is not the norm, but it is not something that has never happened before.
So, what should be the correct course of action in this case?

I'm just speculating, but one possibility, particularly if the journal is using an online system not adapted to mathematics, is that the status does not reflect the workflow of the actual journal.  In particular, if the journal (like many top math journals) uses a system where they solicit quick opinions from one or two experts before sending out the paper for a careful detailed read, the system may say "Required reviews completed" when the quick opinions have been received, because that's the way the editors find it most convenient to interact with the online system.

I suspect that the editor in charge is either yet unaware of this or is too busy. Alternatively, the review(s) may not be sufficiently helpful. In any case, the editor should act and change the status.
Yes, a polite inquiry is a sensible way forward.

The same thing happened to me when I submitted to Chem Comms—I assume the editor just never checked, despite the reviews being handed in over a week prior. We got the result a day or so after poking the journal for a response (politely, of course).

Glad to hear that you got your response after a polite email. I have two more papers whose status is unknown to me. I dropped two polite emails (1 month apart)  to the editor to know the status of first paper. However, I got no reply from the editor.

It's worth pointing out that the status changes whenever all required reviews are completed, not when all reviews solicited have arrived. For example, if your journal only needs one review per paper, and there are two agreed reviewers, then as soon as one reviewer submits their review the status changes. However, most editors will wait for the second review, hence there is no decision.
That said, there's effectively no drawback to asking for a status update (unless you do it so often they start getting annoyed), so you might as well do it.
